# Existence of the maximum of a linear functional over some function space

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

When optimize $\int_a^b f$ over a function space $f\in\mathcal{F}$ (say, $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of $L^1([a,b])$ with $a,b$ finite). Note $f$ might not be continuous. In general, what assumption we should make on the function space $\mathcal{F}$ to ensure the maximum of $\int_a^b f$ exists (supremum is attained)? Is compactness of the function space necessary or sufficient?

Comment: You might want functions in $\mathcal{F}$ to be integrable.

Comment: @DiegoArtacho You're right, thanks!

Comment: Compactness is sufficient but not necessary: If $\mathcal F= \{ f\in L^1: \ \int_a^bf=0\}$ then the minimum is attained but the set is not compact.

Comment: @daw Thanks for the example. Any hint on where does the sufficiency come from?

Comment: @JoeLi The sufficiency of compactness comes from the fact that any continuous function on a compact set attains its maximum and minimum values. In the context of optimization problems over function spaces, we often use the concept of weak* compactness, which is a weaker form of compactness, and the Banach-Alaoglu theorem. The Banach-Alaoglu theorem states that in the dual space of a normed vector space, the closed unit ball is weak* compact.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a subset of $L^1([a,b])$ equipped with the weak* topology, and suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is compact. Let $J: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the functional defined by $J(f) = \int_a^b f$. Since the integral is a linear functional, $J$ is continuous with respect to the weak* topology on $\mathcal{F}$. By the Extreme Value Theorem, since $\mathcal{F}$ is compact and $J$ is continuous, there exists an $f^* \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $J(f^*) = \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} J(f)$, which means the maximum is attained. However, as @daw pointed out, compactness is not necessary

Comment: @rumathe Thank you!